# Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 2

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a Google Sheets script to copy the display values from one sheet on a workbook to another sheet on a workbook. However, I am receiving the following error message, "Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 2." Here is the code

```
 function GEDailyData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Historical Price Data');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Rare Current Prices');
  var value2 = sheet2.getRange('C2').getDisplayValue();
  var value3 = sheet2.getRange('C3').getDisplayValue();
  var values = [[value2, value3]];
  var range = sheet.getRange("C2:C3");
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

I tried replacing the values2 and values3 variables in values with just "200" and "300", but I got the same error. Not sure where I am going wrong, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems like the problem stems from it not liking that the Range is within the same Column and not amongst multiple columns. When changing "C2:C3" to "C2:D2", it works.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using the wrong syntax for the .setValues function. The correct layout for the values variable is the following:

```
var values = [[value2],[value3]];
```

This returns the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function GEDailyData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var values = sheet2.getRange('C2:C3').getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values));
  sheet1.getRange(2,3,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}

Execution log
5:19:23 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:19:23 PM  Info    [["value in c2"],["value in c3"]]
5:19:25 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```